# On a characterization of abelian groups $G$ based on special commutator relations ($\exists n\in\Bbb N$ s.t. $[x^n,y]=[x,y^{n+1}],\forall x,y \in G$).

Tags: group-theory, abelian-groups, group-homomorphism

Let $G$ be a group.  If $\exists n\in \mathbb N$ such that $x^n=yx^n(y^{n+1}x)^{-1}xy^n,\forall x,y\in G$, then how to prove that $G$ is abelian?

[Thoughts:](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3055557/on-a-characterization-of-abelian-groups-based-on-special-commutator-relations/3055634#comment6299687_3055557) the condition is same as saying $[x^n,y]=[x,y^{n+1}],\forall x,y \in G$, where $[a,b]:=a^{-1}b^{-1}ab$.

Comment: *Potentially helpful observations:* (1) The equation holds for the generators of the group in particular. (2) The LHS is a subword of the RHS, so $g^n=h^kg^n((h^{n+1}g)^{-1}gh^n)^k$ for all generators $g,h$ of $G$ and all $k\in\Bbb N$.

Comment: @Shaun: the condition also relates to commutators ... see my latest edit ...

Comment: Why use the [tag:group-homomorphism] tag?

Comment: @Shaun: no particular reason ... could be related ...

Comment: If you could prove that $x[x,y] = [x,y]x$ and $y[x,y]=[x,y]y, \forall x, y \in G$, then you are done, because then you have that $[x^n,y] = [x,y]^n = [x,y^n], \forall x,y \in G$.